# How can one solve house price prediction problem with probabilistic graphical models?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, graphical-model

For predicting house prices one typical way is to create a dataset with various input variables (such as area of the house, number of rooms, etc.) and the output variable (price of the house) and then use some regression method (such as regression trees) to learn the relation between the input variables and the output variable.

I cannot see how we can solve this problem with probabilistic graphical models (PGMs).

The canonical example given for a PGM is the student graph below:

[image]

In this graph the relations between Difficulty, Grade, Letter, etc. are given. This can be viewed as a representation of the domain knowledge. The conditional probability distribution tables normally are not known. But if we have some data, we can estimate the values in these tables. According to my understanding, this is the basic learning technique in PGMs.

Now, if we come back to the house sales price prediction, we have features such as size, built year, number of rooms, price etc. But normally we do not have a graph representation showing the relations between these features. For ML methods such as random forests or SVMs this is not a problem, we just train our model on data. But for PGMs we need some graph structure showing the relationships between the features. How can we create this graph structure for sales price prediction? Should we consult domain experts? Or are PGMs not suitable for this problem? Note that here house price prediction is an example problem in order to make my question concrete. This question also applies to other similar problems with tabular data such as fraud detection, churn prediction, etc.

Thanks

**Question**:

1. What methods can you use for structure detection in graphs?
2. Is PGM suitable for house sales prediction?